# WatiN - Failure: System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed

Tags: c#, watin, nunit-2.5

Ok so I have been experimenting with Unit Testing. I am using Nunit and WatiN to do my testing and decided to try to implement the WatiN Test Recorder. I don't know if anyone is familiar with it, but I am using the 2.0 build (beta) I have the following code pulled direcltly from the test recorder and only slightly cleaned up.

```
 [TestFixture, RequiresSTA]
class WatiNTesting
{
    [Test]
    public void WatiNTest()
    {
        IE window = new IE("http://www.google.com");
        TextField txt_q = window.TextField(Find.ByName("q"));
        Element Locate = window.Element(Find.ByText("") && Find.ByValue("") && Find.ById("") && Find.BySrc("") && Find.ByUrl(""));
        Link lnk_wwwvietnamesetestingboardorgzbxemiddownloadcategory197510 = window.Link(Find.ByUrl("http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/?mid=download&category=197510"));

        txt_q.TypeText("Watin");
        Locate.Click();
        lnk_wwwvietnamesetestingboardorgzbxemiddownloadcategory197510.Click();
        window.Dispose();            
    }
}
```

Whenever I go to run it, the window opens to goolge then Nununit returns this error:

```
Failure: System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

Does anyone know how to get rid of this error, or a way to get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the first problem seems to be with the Find.ByUrl call on this line...

```
Element Locate = window.Element(Find.ByText("") && Find.ByValue("") && 
    Find.ById("") && Find.BySrc("") && Find.ByUrl(""));
```

Remove it...

```
Element Locate = window.Element(Find.ByText("") && Find.ByValue("") &&
    Find.ById("") && Find.BySrc(""));
```

And it passes.  Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but hope this helps.

Comment: It is not me, that was provided by the WatiN Test Recorder...I thought the recorder would make my life easier but it seems it has just made it more complicated haha. However, removing that line did not make it work. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried locating something like this:

```
Link link = window.Link(Find.By("rawurl", "http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/?mid=download&category=197510"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring due to the presence of the ? character in your URL and the way WatiN internally operates while performing a find operation

You might want to try this

```
Link lnk_wwwvietnamesetestingboardorgzbxemiddownloadcategory197510 = window.Link(Find.ByUrl(new Regex(@"^http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/\?mid=download&category=197510$")));
```

This uses a Regex overload for finding the URL and will escape the ? character.

Comment: Still not working. The application Opens a google window and types in WatiN then after about 1 minute it returns this message:               " Failure: WatiN.Core.Exceptions.ElementNotFoundException : Could not find  element tag matching criteria: '''Attribute 'innertext' matches '^ * *$'' And 'Attribute 'value' equals '''' And 'Attribute 'id' equals '''' And 'Attribute 'src' equals ''' at http://www.vietnamesetestingboard.org/zbxe/?document_srl=432065 (inner exception: Access is denied."

Comment: Is there a link with that src attribute present in the DOM when you, when you attempt to click it? Why don't you try removing the ^ and the $ from the Regex? That might help. The exception that you see right now, is because you are attempting to click a link that does not exist in the DOM at the time when you are clicking it. The exception that you were getting earlier because the URL resolution was failing because of invalid characters (when used within a REGEX).